# How to name the index of a mongo json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to write a document in mongo with a string instead of a number in the index of the array, but I'm not succeeding. Is it possible to do that?

Example:

This is a simple array declared in json in javascript:

```
var models = {

    'Casa1A': {

        'X': 6,
        'Y': 4,
        'Image': 'house1A'

    }

};
```

I can use it like this:

```
alert(models['Casa1A'].x);
```

I'd like to do the same in a mongo collection, but I'm not getting it.

```
var modelModels = new mongoose.Schema ({
    
        X: Number,
        Y: Number,
        Image: String
   
});
exports.models = mongoose.model('models', modelModels);
```

But to use I have to do with numbers:

```
alert(models[0].x);
```

How do I use `models['casa1A']`?

Comment: is 'casa1A' field name dynamic?

Comment: yes, dynamic field name, string field name.